# What creates the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys

I understand that by default the `id` field is created and also: `PRIMARY KEY (`id`)`.

How about the foreign key ?

I have `Shops` and `Products` tables and the following associations:

```
Shop:    has_many :products
Product: belongs_to :shop
```

In `Product` I have also:

```
t.integer "shop_id"
```

which is meant to be the foreign key, and also:

```
add_index("products", "shop_id")
```

However, if I export the database I see only:

```
KEY `index_products_on_shop_id` (`shop_id`)
```

What should I do in order to add

```
FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES Shop(`id`)
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) gem for adding foreign keys to your application. To get started add the following to your `Gemfile`

```
gem "foreigner"
```

After that you can easily add foreign keys in your migration like so:

```
add_foreign_key :products, :shops
```

This would add a foreign from `product.shop_id` to `shop.id`. See the documentation for more options like differently named keys or self-referencing tables.