# Difference between foreign key constraint and references in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any difference between using `t.references` and executing `SQL` command to create foreign key relationship between `products` and `category` table as shown below? In other words, are the two different ways of doing the same thing or am I missing anything here?

```
class ExampleMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.references :category
    end
    #add a foreign key
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE products
        ADD CONSTRAINT fk_products_categories
        FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES categories(id)
    SQL
    add_column :users, :home_page_url, :string
    rename_column :users, :email, :email_address
  end

  def down
    rename_column :users, :email_address, :email
    remove_column :users, :home_page_url
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE products
        DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_products_categories
    SQL
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some thing intresting in this page.

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=17318

From a comment :

> Rails doesn't use foreign keys to perform his backend tasks.  This
>   because some db like sqlite doesn't allow foreign keys on its tables.
>   So Rails doesn't provide an helper to build a foreign key

Also there is a gem [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) for adding foreign keys to database table.
[What creates the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406075/what-creates-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-ruby-on-rails-3)

Comment: Rails 4.2 now supports foreign key constrains for adapters that support them: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support

Answer (score 3):

They're not the same thing. Rails by default doesn't enforce foreign keys in the database. Instead, references when creating from the command line also creates a regular index, like this:

```
add_index :products, :category_id
```

**Update:**

Rails 5 actually does exactly the same thing now. So, to answer the original question: Nowadays, both are the same.

Comment: So are references in Rails essentially foreign_key + index on that foreign key?

Comment: @geoboy This actually has changed in more recent versions. `t.references` also sets a foreign key with an index. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Comment: That's what I figured. But if I set up the foreign key and index separately, it then has the same effect? Or is there an advantage of having `t.references` in the `schema.db` file (rather than `foreign_key` and `index`)?

Comment: So nowadays, to generate a relationship between two existing tables, say a `Author` and `Books`, do we need just need one of the foreign key or reference? Eg, `rails g migration AddAuthorToBooks author:references` ?

Comment: Nowadays you can add `index: true` to the migration and an index will be created for the association.